# Prove that if $A$ is $n\times n$ matrix then $A^*A$ is positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Prove that if $A$ is $n\times n$ matrix then $A^*A$ is positive semi-definite.

We want to prove for $C=A^*A$, $z^*Cz$ is nonnegative for any non zero vector $z$

so start with $z^*A^*Az= (Az)^* (Az)=|Az|^2$ can we say for this $A^*A $ is positive definite?

How to prove that $B=A+(A^{-1})$ is invertible?

Comment: Can $|Az|^2$ be negative or zero if $z\neq 0$? If not, then you're done.

Comment: @Semiclassical..negative or positive? i think positive or zero ..yeah if $z\neq 0$ then im done what about if z=0

Comment: The definition of positive definite requires $z\neq 0$. Otherwise, you'd always have $z^* Az=0$ when $z=0$ and nothing could ever be positive definite.

Comment: @Semiclassical..okay i think we say that $z^*Az$ is positive for every non zero vector right? can help me with second one

Comment: You need to assume that $A$ is nonsingular if you want $A^*A$ positive definite. Otherwise it's just positive semi-definite.

Comment: @TedShifrin..if assume A is nonsingular then i can prove second

Comment: Note that if $A=0$ then $0^*0 $ is not positive definite.

Comment: $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}$, $A^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$